# Loop and Incrementation in Alignment?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, alignment, increment

Is there a way to loop the alignment code?

Because I want to display this kind of output. Please click [here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/lx9b.jpg/)

How can I change settings of alignment and incrementation of numbers if I'm going to use loop?

This is a sample of the codes I have:

```
 mov cx, 5     ; counter

 try:          ; loop

 mov ah,2      
 mov bh,1      ;1st column number 1
 mov dl,12
 int 10h

 Mov ah, 2
 Mov dl, 49    ; display 1
 int 21h

 mov ah,2      
 mov bh,2      ;2nd column number 1
 mov dl,10
 int 10h

 Mov ah, 2
 Mov dl, 49    ; display 1
 int 21h


 mov ah,2      
 mov bh,2      ;2nd column number 2
 mov dl,14
 int 10h

 Mov ah, 2
 Mov dl, 50    ; display 2
 int 21h

 loop try
```

Please help me.

Thanks =}

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is farily simple. Here's some C-ish code to give you an idea of how to do it (I'll leave the assembly implementation to you since it's your assignment):

```
#define ROWS 5

for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    move_to_xy(ROWS - (row + 1), row);
    for (int column = 0; column < row + 1; column++) {
        printf("%d ", column + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the problem Sir.

I am not that familiar with Assembly's syntax.

I do not know what to used.

Comment: Download the x86 [instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and start reading.